# How do use Random by WebDriverWait?

Tags: c#

I know WebDriverWait use method.

For example:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000));
```

I would like to use a random method to replace 1000 position，please tell me how can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Random random = new Random();
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next()));
```

`random.Next()` can also be customised

For Eg;

`random.Next(0, 1000)` will yield you random values between `0` and `1000`

So your code will become

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next(0,1000)));
```